# OwnerForm loses focus into the background?

Tags: vb6

I'm facing a weird case in VB6, which is, when I show a form in respect with another OwnerForm, if I did this two/three times for example, when I close all the child forms, suddenly the OwnerForm disappear on background (lose focus and the previous application will be on top), and I will have to click on it on the task bar to show the form again!

A quick sample will be something like that:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Command1.Enabled = False
    Dim frm As New Form1
    frm.Show 0, Form1
End Sub
```

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're showing the child form on top non-modally, ie, you can have any number of child forms of that type open. When you close them, sometimes the form / app that spawned them will lose focus and disappear behind other applications - as you are experiencing.

You might be able to hide the form being closed (use the _QueryUnload event and cancel the unload), hide, then set the ZOrder on the parent form (to bring it to the front), then carry on unloading the form that is being closed.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Hi Cometbill,
Thanks for the updates.Yes, this is the idea, which is to show as much forms as I need non-modally (we are talking about large applications here). And am facing this issue all the time actually (not sometimes) when you load more than 2 forms...
I used the _QueryUnload to hide the form instead of unloading it, but still the problem exist (setting the ZOrder for the form will not look logical since I don't know how much forms are loaded, so I will not know when to set the ZOrder). Second thing, I believe hiding will cause memory issues especially when there is large amount of forms

Comment: You're only hiding the form as long as it takes to set the ZOrder on the Parent form, but it sounds like the Parent form is hiding behind other applications, or is it hiding behind (or sitting on top of) the other child forms. In which case you Might need <parent form>.ZOrder 0 , or ZOrder 1 - I can't remember which.

Comment: The Parent form will be hidden behind other Apps (for example Google Chrome) when you close the last child form. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, without tinkering I'm not sure what to suggest. I don't have access to VB6 at the moment. Sounds like you need a way to detect that a child form has closed, and for the parent form to give itself a ZOrder boost when the last child form has been closed.